# Error handling implementation on C static libraries

Tags: c, error-handling, static-libraries

I am implementing a simple static library on C, and I have some basic questions regarding the implementation of error handling.

Lets say for the sake of the example, that my library supports a basic linked list which uses `Node` structure:

```
typedef struct Node
{
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
    int* data;

}Node;


typedef struct LinkedList
{
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;


}LinkedList;
```

And let's say, as a part of the interface that I'm providing - I'm giving an implementation for a function that inserts a new `Node` as the `LinkedList` head

```
void insertHead(LinkedList* LinkedList, Node* node)
{
    if(LinkedList == NULL || node == NULL)
    {
        // How to implement?
    }
}
```

I want to catch the most basic error for example - the user of my library tries to enter a `NULL` pointer. I know that using `stderr` or printing errors is not a good idea, and also - using `assert`s is not a good idea.

I somewhat understand that I need to build my own "error - catching mechanism" using a global variable that holds error codes, and converts into strings (Like enums maybe?).

However - I have no idea how to implement such mechanism, how would the user of my library encounter the error itself? the interface itself (the `.lib` file has only method declerations and such, and the `.c` file has the implementation) - so after linkage and compilation and such, how would the user get to "see" the errors that I'm providing?

I would love to get a brief example on how to handle user input errors, sorry for being a bit unclear - I am just confused.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that using stderr or printing errors is not a good idea, and also - using asserts is not a good idea.

You are right, both would be very bad in a library.

> I somewhat understand that I need to build my own "error - catching mechanism" using a global varibale that holds error codes, and converts into strings (Like enums maybe?).

No need for global variables, that is a bad idea. Providing a human/English-readable string equivalent is not too bad, but not really needed. Leave that to the application (what if they need to localize the string?).

> how would the user of my library encounter the error itself?

Libraries usually provide whatever is needed in one or more header files that the user of the library `#include`s.

---

The easiest way is to have your functions return an error code:

```
Error insertHead(LinkedList* LinkedList, Node* node)
{
    if(LinkedList == NULL || node == NULL)
    {
        return LINKEDLIST_ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT;
    }
}
```

Here `Error` can be just an integer and `LINKEDLIST_ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT` a `#define`. Another option is using an `enum`. These definitions would be in the header file you give to users of your library.

Your callers will only need to do:

```
#include <yourlibrary.h>

// ...
{
    if (insertHead(...) != ERROR_OK)
        // whatever they need to do with the error
}
```

Comment: So basically just macro error codes using `#define`?

Comment: @WillC99997 Or an enum, yes.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that many of my methods return a certain data type that won't support this implementation - so I will have to use a global variable that saves a current error code or something I guess.

Comment: @WillC99997 Use a return parameter instead for the output data type to free the return one.